# Alamofire not sending the current headers (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I keep getting "error_type":"OAuthException","code":"41" when I using alamofire or even when i made it through to the server I got data from before header's authorisation. I think it keep sending same header, how to make sure that alamofire send the current headers?

```
    let headers = ["Authorization" : "\(AccessToken) \(TokenType)"]
    print(headers)

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "url/profile/", headers: headers, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {}
```

**EDIT**
First, I use login API

```
    let parameters = [
        "client_id": "\(Constant.clientId)",
        "client_secret": "\(Constant.clientSecret)",
        "response_type": "\(Constant.responseType)",
        "scope" : "\(Constant.scope)",
        "redirect_uri": "\(Constant.redirect)",
        "email": "\(email!)",
        "password": "\(pass!)"

    ]

    print(parameters)

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://url/login/", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:

            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                print("JSON: \(json)")
                let accessToken = json["access_token"].string!
                let refreshToken = json["refresh_token"].string
                let tokenType = json["token_type"].string!
                let expiresIn = json["expires_in"].string
 }
```

And then, I use `accessToken` and `tokenType` for authorization

```
 if(refreshToken != nil)
                {
 let headersCust = ["Authorization" : "\(accessToken) \(tokenType)"]
                    print(headersCust)
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://goodies.co.id/api/v1/customer/profile/", headers: headersCust, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually this problem is caused by `Redirection`. Using some networking debugging tool like **Proxyman** helps you to understand if this is a case; if so :

this is Alamofire 5(AF 5) solution:

```
let headers: [String:String] = [...]
let params: [String: Any] = [...]
let url = URL(...)
let redirector = Redirector(behavior: Redirector.Behavior.modify({ (task, urlRequest, resp) in
  var urlRequest = urlRequest
  headers.forEach { header in
    urlRequest.addValue(header.value, forHTTPHeaderField: header.key)
  }
  return urlRequest
  }))
  //use desired request func of alamofire and your desired enconding
  AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                //handleDataResponse...
            }.redirect(using: redirector)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using the latest `Alamofire` so here is the code for `.GET` Request:

```
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", headers: headers)
         .responseJSON { response in
             debugPrint(response)
         }
```

Reference: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
Try this out! And make sure you are sending the proper headers.

Comment: i'm using alamofire 3, i think its the latest, it only happen in .GET with headers @Sohil

Comment: @AldoLazuardi Have you tried confirming your request using the POSTMAN?

Comment: in postman it shows same data that i got on debuger, i think it's not headers problem, i think when i got wrong authorization. the thing is it's not server/API fault because it works fine in another platform (android/web). let me edit my question to explain how i got authorization