# Swift. Alamofire doesn't send Bearer Authorization header with particular request

Tags: swift, authorization, alamofire

I have a request constructor:

```
   AF.request(
        baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path),
        method: method,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: encoding,
        headers: .init([.authorization(bearerToken: token)]),
        interceptor: nil,
        requestModifier: nil
    )
```

And 4 paths:

1. `"/api/v1/languages"`
2. `"/api/v1/speak"`
3. `"/api/v1/courses/\(id)" // where id is Int`
4. `"/api/v1/courses/1"`

**The problem is the first two requests work good (with Authorization), but the last two - not. In these cases Authorization is added in original request, but is not included in current.**

I mean, I check with that:

```
print("debug1", request?.lastTask?.currentRequest, request?.lastTask?.currentRequest?.headers)
print("debug2", request?.lastTask?.originalRequest, request?.lastTask?.originalRequest?.headers)
```

And the first one includes an Authorization header only with the two first requests.
The second one includes an Authorization header in any case.

Tested with these paths:
`"/api/v1/70"` - auth exists
`"/api/v1/courses/70"` - auth doesn't exist
`"/api/v1/courses/courses/70"` - auth exists
`"/api/v1/episodes/70"` - auth doesn't exist
`"/api/v1/episodes/episodes/70"` - auth exists

Comment: I guess there are redirections and that's the issue. Could you check the "full URL" in working vs non-working cases, and see if that's correct. There is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305945/alamofire-not-sending-the-current-headers-swift with a work around, but I'm wondering if it shouldn't be done inside Alamofire to "reput" all the headers (or is it a param/bug to set?)

Comment: See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/798 if it's indeed due to redirections

Comment: @Larme no, there are no any redirections unfortunately